# Czech national identity card validation

Tags: algorithm, validation, identity

I'm looking for CZ national idenity card number validation algorithm. There can be 9 or 10 digits sequenced by special algoritm, but there are not just numbers :) I've found this function:

```
function checkId(id) {

    var x, sum_nb=0, check;
    var steps = new Array(7,3,1,7,3,1,7,3);
    id = id.toUpperCase(),
    splitted = id.split("");

    if (splitted.length != 9 && splitted.length != 10) {return false;}

    for (x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        if (x == 0 || x == 1 || x == 2) {
            sum_nb += steps[x] * parseInt(id.charCodeAt(x)-55);
        }
        if (x > 3) {
            sum_nb += steps[x-1] * parseInt(id.charAt(x));
        }
    }

    check = sum_nb % 10;

    if (check == id.charAt(3))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

But I'm not sure that it's correct. Is anyone knows correct algoritm? It can be written on any language, it does not matter.

Comment: Where did you find this function?  And how could we possibly know whether or not it implements the correct algorithm?

Comment: The Czech national ID card has two numbers: a document number and the owner's birth number. Which are you referring to? The latter is documented here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Czech_Republic_and_Slovakia

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I know that it's not correct because i tested it on various real identity numbers.

Comment: @Jordan I'm talking about this document and its document number - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_national_identity_card. There is nothing about its format.

Comment: @astrikovd you should find a solid information source for this not some Wiki page. Try asking someone from  Bureau of Customs
 (Celní správy) idealy from IT unofficially of coarse because such inquiries can be suspicious. Also try finding if there is not some §law document about this if you're lucky may be you find all what you need in there.